# How to thwart IP detection when using tor-proxies with WebRTC in Firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, p2p

```
      (Config: FF 40.x on an Ubuntu 14.04.3 box, along with Tor 0.2.4.27)
```

I use Tor proxies in different countries to gain normal access to a number of specific URLs from their countries of origin when they impose geographic conditions on access.

In case of WebRTC detection of my private IP address, I see on https://ipleak.net/#webrtcleak, that WebRTC implement STUN (Session Traversal Utilities for Nat), a protocol that allows to discover the public IP address of a distant request-sender. To disable it on Mozilla Firefox, the page recommends I toggle the value of “media.peerconnection.enabled” to "false" (in about:config).

All I know is WebRTC is instrumental (required ?) in making possible a lot of P2P protocols such as "FF Hello" which I haven't used so far.

- What are the adverse or otherwise restrictive implications (e.g. for the operability of FF or of any other P2P application) if I proceed to toggle the value of “media.peerconnection.enabled” to false in FF ?
- Could one thwart IP detection while using tor proxies without disabling WebRTC in FF ?